# Ajax not working on select tag, PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax on a select tag with 2 options, but it's not getting the $_POST for some reason. It prints out the "---", but it does not print out the $_POST value, which is either 1 or 2. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

**newtest.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,type,theName,id) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { select: $(type+'[name='+theName+']').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>

<?php

echo "<select name = 'name' onchange = 'ajax(\"newtestx.php\",\"input\",\"name\",\"output\")'>";
echo "<option value = '1'> 1 </option>";
echo "<option value = '2'> 2 </option>";
echo "</select>";

echo "<div id = 'output'></div>";

?>
```

**newtestx.php**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name."---";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a POST parameter with the key "select" to the server in your AJAX call:

```
   data: { select: $(type+'[name='+theName+']').val()},
```

In newtestx.php you are trying to retrieve the value from a POST parameter with the key "name" - which doesn't exist:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

You could fix this easily by giving the parameter keys the same name. If you would look for $`name = $_POST['select']` the parameter would be found.

Inline Javascript is considered bad practice and there's no need to echo out the HTML markup, it makes the mark up harder to work with.

**newtest.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="[link to your javascript file here]"></script>
<select name='numbers' class="postValueOnChange" data-id-to-update="output" data-post-url="newtestx.php">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<div id='output'></div>
```

**Javascript file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.postValueOnChange').change(postSelectedValue);

    function postSelectedValue(e) {
        var $self = $(this);
        var url = $self.data('post-url');
        var $elementToUpdate = $('#' + $self.data('id-to-update'));

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                selected: $self.val()
            }
        });
        jqxhr.done(function (data) {
            $elementToUpdate.html(data);
        });
        jqxhr.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        });
    }
});
```

**newtestx.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['selected'];
echo $name."---";
?>
```

Comment: You wrote a whole new code for ajax. Can you tell me which part of my code is wrong, and fix that part for me? Unless, the whole thing is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending post param `select` and trying to receive as `$_POST['name']`.

Make sure they match...either both as `name` or as `select`

Comment: change the property name in ajax data or in `$_POST` in php

Comment: I changed $name = $_POST['select']; but it didn't do anything.

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab to see what's happening. Check status, what is sent and what is returned (if any)

Comment: also doesn't make sense that `type` is `input` for a `<select>`. Much better as mentioned below to get rid of inline onchange code

Comment: I changed the type to 'select' but it also didn't do anything.

Comment: `didn't do anything` is not a proper inspection of the actual request in network tab

Comment: This answer (and comments)  are normally pointing a big problem you have

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers It would be really nice if I actually understood the answer. It would make it a lot easier for me to understand the answer if someone provides any example of the part of the code that is wrong, and provides a right example of what it should be.

Comment: @frosty... it is assumed that you understand what the data object is and what post keys are at server...otherwise you probably need to study some more basics in php manual and jQuery ajax docs. Lots of tutorials around to learn how this works

Comment: @charlietfl If you know what I did wrong, and want to help me, it takes 10 seconds to post the part that I did wrong, and that would make me understand what I did wrong. Otherwise, even if you keep trying to explain without any examples, I won't understand, and it won't help me any.

Comment: inspect the request in browser dev tools...we can't do that for you

Comment: @charlietfl No. I'm talking about the part where you said "Make sure they match...either both as name or as select". Which part of the code is not matching? Can you post the part of the code that's not matching, and then a matching version of the code? Thank you.

Comment: Did you understood the third comment of charlie about type `...is input for a <select>...`, I think you are not understanding what your function is doing

Answer (score 0):

First, Since you are using jQuery, why are you still using inline javascript?

Well I suggest you first to restrucure your code around the jQuery `change` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var selected = $('.select option:selected').val();
        var id, theName, url= ...// get it from the DOM 

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: url,
           data: { select: selected},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             $('#'+id).html(data);
           }

      });


    }); 
});
```

Second, why are you coding HTML with PHP, you are making yourself struggle and lose time only with quotes and double quotes, and no-needed spaces.

```
    <form action="">  
        <select name="name">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>


    </form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me which part of my code is causing the malfunctioning, and how to fix it?

Comment: I am trying, but the way you are coding from the beginning doesn't respect the best practices. Better resolve both problems. I am still trying to figure out

Comment: right, when you have numerous mismatches you need to use browser debugging tools to start evaluating what is what and see if variables are as expected and what actually is being communicated with server

Comment: I am totally agreeing with you Charlietfl, `console.log` client side + `var_dump` server-side works well, and network tab to follow HTTP communication.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Please help me figure out which part of the code I did wrong. I'm asking because I don't know what  I did wrong, and trying to get professional help.

Comment: Please to do what others (more professional than me) ask you. inspect the request and response in browser dev tools...

Comment: I would if I know how, but I don't, and that's why I'm asking here.